# Python Recursion Error maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling Python object

Tags: python-3.x

I have a little program written in Python. It is supposed to talk to you like Siri except command line based. It asks you how your day is and when you put good it is supposed to pick 1 out of 5 good responses and say that to you but I keep getting a recursion error here is my code

```
def nice5():
    print ("Well Thats Good!")
   time.sleep(2)
   randsub(2)

def nice4():
    print ("Great!")
    time.sleep(2)
    randsub()

def nice3():
    print ("Thats Good!")
    time.sleep(2)
    randsub()

def nice2():
    print ("Cool I am glad to hear that!")
    time.sleep(2)
    randsub()

def nice1():
    print ("Thats Good! ")
    time.sleep(2)
    randsub()

def nicerand():
    randnices = [nice1 , nice2 , nice3 , nice4 , nice5]
    randnice = random.choice(randnices)
    nicerand()


def p1checkChoice():
    if choice == "Good":
        nicerand()
    if choice == "good":
       nicerand()
    if choice == "GOOD":
       nicerand()




def greeting():
    clearscr()
    name = input("Hello What is your name: ")
    clearscr()
    print ("Hello " + name)
    time.sleep(2)
    clearscr()
    print ("Allow me to introduce myself")
    time.sleep(2)
    clearscr()
    print ("My name is Chatbot")
    time.sleep(2)
    clearscr()
    choice = input("How has your day been: ")
    global choice
    p1checkChoice()
    greeting()
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message and a definition of `Randnices`

Comment: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: `Global choice` with a capital `G`? Please provide the exact source that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There are far too many errors in your sample code to be the actual code you are running; however, the key problem is that `checkChoice` calls `nicerand` which calls any of the `randnices` which call `nicerand` which calls any of the `randnices` which call `nicerand` which calls any of the `randnices` which calls ....

and eventually you hit the `RecursionError`.

The fix is simple:  do not have any of the `randnices` functions call back into `nicerand`; just remove that line from them.

Then they will simply return to `nicerand` which will return to `checkChoice` which can continue whatever it is doing.